# WebUSB for connecting to custom hardware

Tags: webusb

I would like to talk to a custom piece of hardware via my web application using WebUSB
The hardware is already able to communicate to a python script running on a laptop via USB

Now I have 2 questions and I hope you can help me :)

1. Does the hardware need to implement anything WebUSB specific? Or is the USB communication that is already implemented enough?
2. Is WebUSB ready for production? This application will be used by customers to talk to machines like excavators.

The whole application (talking to machines) already works via internet - we just need to implement the USB communication to handle the case that the user doesn't have a working internet connection.

best,
Kev

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Does the hardware need to implement anything WebUSB specific? Or is the USB communication that is already implemented enough?

It is enough.

> 2. Is WebUSB ready for production? This application will be used by customers to talk to machines like excavators.

The Chrome team takes the decision to make a Web API available to developers very seriously and is committed to supporting these APIs for the long term. The [draft status of the WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) should not be taken as a reflection of the Chrome team commitment to this work. It is a necessary effect of how the web standardization process works.

The WebUSB API has been available for quite some time and is considered stable. While we have been making steady investments in the implementation of the API there are no changes to the developer-facing interface planned.

Comment: Wow that's good news! Thanks a lot! :) We can control the USB device class of the hardware - do you know which one would work best? I read HID is not working. We thought about CDC because that's what an arduino would be, but we are just randomly guessing

Comment: Why is HID not working for you?

Comment: It could work, I didn't try yet. I just read that it's not working due to security concerns in a post or tutorial. Does HID work?

Comment: WebHID works great if your HID interface is uncommon (not like keyboard, camera, etc.) See https://web.dev/hid and https://web.dev/devices-introduction/ for more on this topic.